# css alignement issues text dispalying in 3 lines

Tags: css

please visit the link :

here "CASH ON DELIVERY" and " DELIVERY BY" part is not looking good.

means it's not like

5 business days is dispalying in 3 lines....

Comment: please give the images sign for page

Comment: i did't got, do you want screenshot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please Try this code style.css

```
  .Quick .COD {
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        width: 61%;
    }

.Delivery_hover_details > p {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    right: 91px;
    top: 21px;
}
```

Comment: if i use above code, it will display one by one.

Comment: ok i try your question